# Netboot cannot get DHCP IP address

Tags: network, ethernet, netboot

- Testing netboot on a Macbook Pro 9,2 with Yosemite installed.
- Infoblox DHCP/DNS (Linux style) giving out IP address.
- Reservation for this Mac is set - Logging into OSX provides correct IP etc.
- I have a OSX Server with Netinstall running.

If I try a netboot (press N at power on), this results in the globe flashing but eventually just reverts to disk boot. Checking the Netinstall server logs, there is no activity - the client didn't attempt to conact.

If I try to boot to menu (press Option key), I get an option of booting from the disk, or selecting a WiFi network. There is no ethernet network option. If I press N at this point, nothing happens.

It *appears* that the ethernet port is not working at this stage in the process, even though it works when booting to OSX. Can anyone advise? How can I check this?

Using the latest available:

- BOOTROM: MBP91.00D3.B08 (EFI 2.9)
- SMC: 2.2f44 (SMC 1.8)

Comment: Is your computer on the same network/subnet as the OSX Server?

Comment: It is, but at this stage it seems like I can't even get a network connection which is what I'm trying to troubleshoot. There is no option to network boot from the ethernet, it seems. Doing a straight network boot (N key) shows no traffic/requests using wireshark...

Comment: https://forums.networkinfrastructure.info/general-discussion/netboot-with-a-mac-and-infoblox-as-dhcp-server/  ---take a look at this article, you may need to enable some options on the infoblox

Comment: Infoblox already has the options enabled, but it's not even making the BOOTP request. It's appears to be a client issue where the ethernet port is not detected - I can't seem to choose the ethernet port to boot from. I've just checked on a normal Mac, and I have the same issue: If I boot to the boot option screen (press OPTION at startup), there is no way to network boot - as if there is no network. However, in OSX everything is fine.

Comment: Might be a dumb question but is the netboot image enabled on OS X server, and what do the netinstall logs show?

Comment: Yes, there is an image enabled, but I'm not at that stage yet. It's the client that is not picking up ethernet. As I said in my post, the Netinstall logs show NOTHING. No communication at all. More importantly - WIRESHARK shows NO ACTIVITY from the client. My initial query is regarding troubleshooting the ethernet connection during netboot time on the client, not on the server.

Comment: Managed to tweak infoblox settings correctly - I made OSX server a DHCP server on a closed subnet, and captured the boot options. Once I had those, I ported them to Infoblox and managed to get booting OK.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a way to confirm that the client is getting a correct DHCP entry at this stage (no logs, etc). Packet sniffing helped.

Basically, the incorrect options in DHCP was preventing communication with the Netboot server, but with no diagnostics on the client, it was fairly hard to troubleshoot.

Managed to tweak infoblox settings correctly - I made OSX server a DHCP server on a closed subnet, and captured the boot options. Once I had those, I ported them to Infoblox and managed to get booting OK